# Apply numpy interpolation function with index array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an index-matrix and a matrix with my variables of same sizes:

```
 index = [a, c, c, b]
 m = [0.23, 0.45, 1, 0.7]
```

Now I need to apply an interpolation function using the variables in m, however based on the index in the index-matrix I need to choose from different values. So my values where to interpolate between:

```
a = [(1, 0), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.6)]
b = [(1, 0), (2, 0.5), (3, 0.9)]
c = [(1, 0), (2, 0.3), (3, 0.5)]
```

So, for the first calculation the value is 0.23 and the index a. So I need to apply numpy.interp using the coordinates in a and so on.

I can zip index and m and apply numpy.interp on a value by value basis. But since I need to apply this to huge datasets I would like a quicker way.